# Vert.x - limit single instance verticle in all cluster

Tags: java, locking, microservices, distributed, vert.x

I have a `Vert.x` application with several verticls to interact with different **buses** and **dbs** (mongo, redis, rabbit, kafka and such)

among those there is a verticle dedicated for communication with external api (very old) which allow for one persistent connection and from a single (pre defined) source

I'm deploying mutli instances of vertx with the same code (auto-scale) and make them act as a cluster, using `hazelcast` as a cluster manager

what is the best practice for limiting the creation of the `external-api verticle` to only single instance, I looked at:

- `SharedData.Lock()` - but I'll need to wrap it with an async spinning lock logic
- `High Availability` - great for termination and auto-scaling but doesn't force activity of a single verticle
- `worker verticle` - to create 1 worker verticle in each instance

I could use a mix of all the above and create the desired functionality, but I seems some what complex...

should I separate my verticle to a different server or there is some simpler solution I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: `SharedData.Lock()` would let you create a dedicated connection to your legacy api, but of course it won't forbid create multiple instances of the same verticle.

Comment: I would recommend running this on a separate server/pod, as having "exactly one" is not something Vert.x attempts to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need single verticle , leave that verticle to be just stateless and apply your connections in Proxy service - after you can register that service as  HttpEndpoint , Evenbus , Message or JDBC service types and you will have single point of comminication with db or external http source.